# How to install the new version of "PokerTH" game via terminal?

Tags: command-line, games

I was trying to install "PokerTH" with Ubuntu software center but it installed an older version of the game.

When I ran the game it told me that I must install the newest version of game to play this game online.

How can I install the newest version via terminal?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Tried this PPA? https://launchpad.net/~pkg-games/+archive/ppa

Comment: i use, ubuntu 12.10, i don't know how to use PPA, i don't know what to run in terminal exactly, if you tell me how and then i will try to use that PPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pkg-games
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pokerth
```

See also: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the pokerTH teams PPA.

You can get the PPA for ubuntu 12.10 from the games Launchpad site.
https://launchpad.net/~pkg-games/+archive/ppa

To add a PPA, open your terminal (CTRL+T or search the dash)

type in

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pkg-games/ppa

it will ask for your root password (admin) and you will not see anything as you type it in, but that's alright. After writing the password hit RETURN / ENTER

Then you will have to update all you software sources, by typing:

> sudo apt-get update

and finally you can install the game

> sudo apt-get install pokerth